# Поле ввода после выбора элемента из выпадающего списка

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не могу понять в чем дело. Должно при выборе "Социальная сеть" из выпадающего списка, ниже появляться поле ввода для возможности внесения ссылки на  данную социальную сеть.

```js
function i() {
 var social = document.getElementById("social");
 var selectSocial = social.option[social.selectedIndex].value;
 if (selectSocial == "soc") {
  var show = document.getElementById("show");
  show.style.display = inherit;
 }
}
```

```css
input {
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 15px;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 5px 0;
            width: 80%;
            border: 2px solid blue;
            border-radius: 5px;
}
 #show {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<form action="server.php" method="POST">
        <p> Желаемый способ связи:</p>
        <select name="connection" id="social">
          <option value="telegram">Telegram</option>
          <option value="soc">Социальная сеть</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Введите ссылку или фио в соц.сети" id="show">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Массив вариантов выбора это не `social.option` а `social.options`
2. `css` значение свойства `'inherit'` это строка а у Вас ссылка на несуществующую переменную.
3. Так же требуется обратное действие, как я полагаю:

```js
function i() {
 var social = document.getElementById("social");
 var selectSocial = social.options[social.selectedIndex].value;
 var isSocial = selectSocial == "soc"
  var show = document.getElementById("show");
  show.style.display = isSocial ? 'inherit': 'none';
 
}
```

```css
input {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="server.php" method="POST">
  <p> Желаемый способ связи:</p>
  <select name="connection" id="social" onchange="i()">
    <option value="telegram">Telegram</option>
    <option value="soc">Социальная сеть</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Введите ссылку или фио в соц.сети" id="show">
</form>
```